# Change Logo settings on Wordpress in a Responsive way

Tags: html, css, wordpress, responsiveness

I'm a newbie when it comes to coding (this is my first website) but I'm trying to modify the logo on my website. I would like to make it bigger and central. I am able to achieve this from the desktop view but it doesn't work on the mobile.

Briefly, the logo looks quite small on both devices, desktop and smartphone. So I add this code in Custom CSS (found on the web...):

```
.logo.logo1 {
   width:100%;
   text-align:center;
   margin-bottom:20px;

}

.logo.logo1 {
    width: 400px;
    height: 100px;
}

.logo.logo1 {
  position: relative;
  top: 40px;
  right: 130px;
}
```

With this in place, on my desktop the logo looks nice but on my smartphone it is small and goes too far to the very left of the screen, partially disappearing.

As I'm now approaching to coding, I have no idea whether it depends on a potential logo container or how to make it responsive on the smartphone. Truth is that the more research I do, the more I get confused.

Any help about how to fix this would be very appreciated :)

P.S. the website is [this one](https://gesvape.com)

Gio

Comment: Perfect! It works! Thank you very much guys. You both have been very helpful.

Comment: Yw.  Btw, you did an excellent job composing this question.  It made it very easy to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to your css at the bottom.

```
@media (max-width: 767px){
   .logo.logo1{
     max-width: 100%;
     width: 100%;
     position: static;
     top: 0;
     right: 0;
     height: auto;
   }
}
```

Basically, what's going on here is that you are overriding a bunch of styles that your theme applies that make it tiny on small devices.

Comment: I'm sure I'm not getting the point right. I'm adding the css you've provided me with at the bottom of style-mb.css (as suggested by @hossein barzegari too I guess). However, nothing seems to change. I also tried to add it via style.css in the child theme and in the Custom CSS in the WordPress Dashboard but unfortunately, nothing is happening.

Where is my mistake?

Comment: Oops.  I see a typo in my answer.  I left out a '.' before the logo.  I fixed it now. If making that change doesn't work you might also try changing that line to `#header .logo.logo1 {`

Answer (score 0):

you should change css in media section for mobile view. use somethings like below :

```
@media (max-width: 767px){
/*
 your css tags
*/
}
```

special in this issue you should change **style-mb.css** file in line **3048** and change your logo size

**note:** you can use mobile view in your browser to test mobile view in your desktop browser in developer tools